# API key not valid for a firebase, nextjs, vercel project in local dev environment

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

This wasn't a problem before and is currently not a problem in my production deployment.  But now I get this response when I start up my dev environment and try google OAuth signin:

**"API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key."**

This is my firebase setup:

```js
// firebase.js

import "firebase/auth";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

if (typeof window !== "undefined" && !firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECTID
  })

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
}

export { firebase };
```

```js
// .env.local

NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY=<private>
NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN=<private>
NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECTID=<private>
```

When looking at the http request made from both environments, there are two differences in the urls:

deployed: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig?key=(api key)=(some random number)

development: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig?key=(api key)=(some random number)

The api keys are exactly the same but the (some random number) are different.  I don't know if this reveals anything but that's all I can see that's different.  I'm not sure as to what happened because this was working before both in dev and in the deployed version.  Now it just works only in the deployed.

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate you development api key?

Comment: I might end up doing that but I don't think it's a key problem.  I have another app that basically uses the same configuration and works just fine, but it hasn't been deployed yet to production.  I think something happened after I deployed this.

Comment: Well, I think it is exactly the key problem here, you are using same api key for production and dev, and with Oauth it is probably bound to domain (or redirect uri) or something like that.